# No main picture in Preview bundled with Snow Leopard Server ...running in Parallels in Big Sur

Tags: snow-leopard, preview, graphics, parallels-desktop

With aid from Parallels support I have Snow Leopard Server running well in Parallels on my Mac Book Pro running Big Sur , ( intel) .
The version of PREVIEW evidently bundled with the SL server has a peculiar fault ...EVERYTHING else in Preview works fine but there is no MAIN picture in the large central panel . There is another peculiarity in that the version number in "get info" and "about preview" are different .
Since this program is built in , in the various Mac OS's , I am betting there is no .dmg file that will reinstall the proper version for Snow Leopard or SL Server . Has anyone else run into this problem ... see pictures ...[image]

[image]

Comment: I suspect this is a Parallels issue, best answered by Parallels Support.